# Eigenvectors of sum of symmetric block matrices

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, block-matrices

Suppose that we have a symmetric block matrix of the following form:
$$ S = 
\begin{pmatrix}
    S_{11} & \ldots & S_{1m} \\\\
    \vdots & \ldots & \vdots \\\\
    S_{m1} & \ldots & S_{mm} 
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{pnm\times pnm},$$ where $$S_{ji}=S_{ij}=\begin{pmatrix}
    K_{ij} & 0_{n \times n(p-1)} \\\\
    0_{n(p-1)\times n} & 0_{n(p-1) \times n(p-1)} 
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{pn\times pn}, \quad K_{ji}=K_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$$ for $i,j=1,\ldots, m$. Furthermore, there is a second symmetric (left upper) blockmatrix
$$ T = 
\begin{pmatrix}
    T_{11} & \ldots & \ldots & T_{1m} \\\\
    \vdots &  & ⋰ & 0 \\\\
    \vdots &  ⋰ & & \vdots \\\\
    T_{m1} & 0 & \ldots & 0 
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{pnm\times pnm}$$ where $$T_{ji}=T_{ij}=\begin{pmatrix}
    0_{n \times n} & B_{ij}^{12} \\\\
    B_{ij}^{21} & 0_{n(p-1) \times n(p-1)} 
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{pn\times pn}, \quad B_{ij}^{12} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n(p-1)}, B_{ij}^{21} \in \mathbb{R}^{n(p-1)\times n}.$$ Suppose now, that I know all eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $S$ and $T$. Can I determine the eigenvectors of the sum $S+T$ depending on the eigenvectors of $S,T$, respectively? Please note that when adding these two block matrices, it will never be the case that two non-zero matrices are added. I would be very thankful for hints.

Comment: It might be helpful to use a permutation similarity to restructure these matrices. In particular, I believe that there exists a single permutation matrix $P$ such that
$$
PSP^T= \pmatrix{K & 0\\0 & 0},
$$
where $K$ is the block matrix 
$$
K = \pmatrix{K_{11} & \cdots & K_{1m}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
K_{m1} & \cdots & K_{mm}},
$$
and 
$$
PTP^T = \pmatrix{0 & B^{12}\\ B^{21} & 0},
$$
where...

Comment: ...
$$
B^{ij} = \pmatrix{B^{ij}_{11} & \cdots & B^{ij}_{1m}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
B^{ij}_{m1} & \cdots & B^{ij}_{mm}},
$$
with $B^{ij}_{pq} = 0$ whenever $p + q > m + 1$.

Comment: That said, even for the simple case where we're adding the matrices
$$
S = \pmatrix{K & 0\\0 & 0}, \quad T = \pmatrix{0 & B^{12}\\ B^{21} & 0},
$$
there is no nice way to use the eigenvalues of $S$ and $T$ to determine the eigenvalues of $S + T$. If $n$ is small compared to $p$, then you could potentially speed up computation by using the diagonalization of $K$ to implement rank-one updates to the diagonalization of $T$ along the lines of [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/143375/34894), but I don't think that there's any way to get any kind of closed form

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you very much for your comment. I considered this special case too. For my matrices $K$ and $B^{12}, B^{21}$ you end up with a hyperbolic quadratic eigenvalue problem $(\lambda^2 I - \lambda K - B^{12}{B^{12}}^T)x=0$. But again for this problem, it is not clear how the eigenvectors $x$ are connected with the original ones of $S$ and $T$.